# Is this an Activity Memory Leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In the code below there is a memory leak when the activity gets destroy upon orientation.

My question is: Does the whole activity  get leaked or just the object company? If we would pass the view button, then we would have leaked the whole activity?

Thank you.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Company co;
private Button b

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    b= findViewById();
    co = new Company()

    new Test().test(co);
}

}

public class Test {


public void test(final Company co){


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     Company c = co                      
                }
            }).start();

}
}
```

Comment: The leakage is the Company instance referenced by the thread that potential could continue running after the Activity is finished. To avoid that, you can wrap the Company instance in the Runnable using a WeakRefence<Company>.

Comment: @Juan So not the Activity itself? If we pass the button view?

Comment: What do you mean by passing the button view?

Comment: @Juan If we replace the Company that we are passing to the test with the button view, will we have a leaked activity?

Comment: Yes, you will be in the same situation with a diferent attribute of the activity. But you can avoid that with the using WeakReference<Button> instead of Button in the Runnable. By the way, the button is missing the R.id.whatever in your code.

Comment: @Juan It will not be the same situation. If we have a reference only to the company object, then the activity will be gb collectable only, on the other hand if we have a reference to the button View, then the whole activity gets leaked.

Comment: Why will it be different? Both are attributes of the Activity, both are initialized in onCreate(). When either of them is passed into the new Thread, when it is set to null in the Activity, a reference will still keep on living in the other Thread until it finishes.